# Mangeto 1.9.1 - PHP can not devide the subtotal by half

Tags: php

I have a really strange problem.

Take a look:

When i do that:

```
$HalfSubtotal  = $address->getSubtotal() - 100; // It's calculating everything right
```

When i do that:

```
$HalfSubtotal  = $address->getSubtotal() / 2; // It's NOT calculating. I tried *0.5 and the result is the same. It's just not allowing me to devide this variable or multipile it.
```

Why i can not devide it and how i can make it?

Comment: What's the output of getSubtotal and what is $HalfSubtotal getting set to?

Answer (score 1):

I would generally avoid using floats for currency calculations. It can be prone to very strange behavior if you're not expecting it (You should read over this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Use arbitrary precision math instead (http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

If you do something like this:

```
$HalfSubtotal = bcdiv($address->getSubtotal(), "2.0", 4);
```

Then you'll get a number like 31.3215, for example. If you change that 4 to a 2 then you just truncate (effectively round down) your answer.

I found this code somewhere to implement rounding, if you want to round up or down:

```
function bcround($number, $precision = 0)
{
    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        if ($number[0] != '-') return bcadd($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
        return bcsub($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
    }
    return $number;
}
```